# how to prevent autoselection of first item in GridView on databind?

Tags: c#, gridview, data-binding, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

When I databind my GridView to an ObservableCollection, the first item of the collection is automatically selected.  The `SelectionMode` property of the GridView is set to `multiple`. Is there some way to prevent this auto-selection?  Or on what event should I listen so that I can reset the `SelectedIndex` of the GridView back to -1?

Comment: maybe takie the first element and set selection to false ?

Comment: the problem with that is that the user may eventually select the first item in the gridview

Comment: ok but selections is one thing and loading data to the view is second. If i understood you you don`t want the default selection after loading not after picking. Or maybe I missunderstood you ?

Comment: i think you have the correct understanding.  when/how would i set the selection to false?

Comment: yes, but I am data-binding in the XAML.  is there an event that I could listen to, and switch the `SelectedIndex` back to -1 on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrenItem` property to `false` on the gridview in xaml

Answer (score 2):

There is acutally a pretty simple solution.  I set the `SelectionMode` of the GridView to `None` in the XAML.  Then, when the page is created, I change the `SelectionMode` to `Multiple`.

```
        publicPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            itemListView.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple;
        }
```

However, the problem I am having seems to be caused by my own program.  This is a workaround for the issue I am having, the autoselection is not the default behavior.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/da7e9f3b-9a3e-47ca-8223-b50539293f5f

Comment: As mentioned in that post on MSDN, the real solution is to set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem on the GridView to False.

Answer (score 1):

My situation is the opposite. I have a `GridView` that was bind to an `ObservableCollection`, and I wanted the 1st item to be selected but it was not! I figured out why that was the case though. There are 2 ways to generate my `ObservableCollection` and depending on which method I chose, the 1st item is either selected or not.

for example, I have a variable ItemList in my viewmodel which I bind to my GridView

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemList { get; private set; }
```

Method 1 (nothing selected)

```
public void getData()
{
    var myList = // get your list here
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
    {
        this.ItemList.add(myList[i]);
    }
}
```

Method 2 (1st item automatically selected)

```
public void getData()
{
    var myList = // get your list here
    this.ItemList = myList
}
```

Comment: in your case, u could just do this `listview.selectedIndex = 0;` to auto select the first item.